Issue with Requirement.txt file to run Python script on Google Cloud
My end game is to run some Python script onto Google Cloud so I can automate some data pipeline; it is my first time setting up something like this.
I seem to be having an issue with the requirement.txt file, which prevents me from running my script successfully.
Could you please help?
On the same subject, since I am running the script onto Google Cloud, do I need to reference the credential.json file that is supposed to identify me on the platform?
I started by scheduling a simple 'hello world' test script without issue. So, I followed up with a more complex script that involved importing various modules. This is when the flow of error messages started to pile up.
Here is the content of my requirement.txt file:
google-cloud-bigquery
pandas
time
os

And here is the code for my main.py file:
import pandas as pd
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time


# Get a dataframe going 

dic = {'Name':['Peter', 'Paul', 'Jack'], 'Sales':[1000,2000,3000]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)


# Setup the BigQuery connection 

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '.\key.json' 
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = client.dataset('Test_Dataset')
table = dataset.table('Test_Table')
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig( autodetect = True )


# Load the dataframe to BigQuery 

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table, job_config=job_config)


# Wait for the job to finish 

while job.state != 'DONE':
    time.sleep(1)
    job.reload()
    print(job.state.title())

print(f'Job result: {job.result()}')

Edit:
After quite a lot of trial and error, I made it work with the below code:
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import base64
import functions_framework


# Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_pubsub(cloud_event):

    # Set up BigQuery client
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # Get a dataframe going 
    dico = {'Name':['Pierre', 'Paul', 'Jaques'], 'Sales':[1000,2000,3000]}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico)

    # Setup the BigQuery connection
    table_id = 'magnetic-guild-431700-a4.Test_DatasetID.Test_Table2'

    # Make an API request
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)

    # Print out the data from Pub/Sub, to prove that it worked
    print(base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]))


by the way in which service of google cloud you are runnig this python code?? i think the question in ambiguious because you can run in multiple sevice to automate your data pipeline and they have diffrent settings for python to run

Where are you running your code? What's your issue? Is your code run locally? And, by the way, do not use service account key file (key.json), it' could become major security breach and concern

@nabinsademba I am (trying) to run my script from 'Cloud Function', with the help of 'Pub/Sub' for the trigger and 'Cloud Scheduler' to schedule.

Salut, @guillaumeblaquiere, and thank you for your comment. I am trying to run this script from Google Cloud so I can have it run without my input. The issue seems to come from the module import part of the code. I believe I have set up my requirement.txt file correctly, but I keep having errors...

which service in google cloud @Maximuluss ??

It's still not clear what your "issue" is. What have you done to install the packages from requirement.txt? (The conventional file name is plural requirements.txt but Python doesn't know or care what you call this file.) What are the actual errors?

@Maximuluss Google Cloud is wide. Are you running your script on a VM? On cloud shell? In a container? If so, deployed where? On a VM? Cloud Run? GKE? Cloud Build? Vertex AI Custom Training? (I'm sure I missed some options...) So, what are you doing and WHERE?

Apologies for the lack of clarity with my question, I have just posted the solution I came up with.

Based on your description, there are a few issues to address in your setup. Here are some suggestions to resolve the problems:
1. Requirements file:
Your requirements.txt file should list each package on a separate line without version numbers (for production deployments, it's recommended to specify version numbers to ensure consistency)
google-cloud-bigquery
pandas

Note: 'time' and 'os' are built-in Python modules and don't need to be in the requirements file.
2. Credentials:
For Google Cloud services, you typically don't need to explicitly set the credentials in your code when running in a Google Cloud environment. Remove this line from your script:
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '.\key.json'

Instead, For local development: Export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable before running your script:
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/your/key.json"

3. BigQuery setup:
Your BigQuery setup can be simplified. Try this approach:
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'your-project.Test_Dataset.Test_Table'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(autodetect=True)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete

print(f"Loaded {job.output_rows} rows into {table_id}")

4. Error handling:
Add proper error handling to catch and log any issues:
try:
    # Your code here
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

5. Logging:
Use Python's logging module instead of print statements for better integration with Google Cloud's logging system:
import logging

logging.info("Job started")
# Your code here
logging.info(f"Loaded {job.output_rows} rows into {table_id}")

These changes should help resolve your issues. If you're still encountering problems, please provide the specific error messages you're seeing.

Hey @CaioPizzol, thank you for your comment.


Shall I paste the line at the start of my code?
Where do I need to save the key.json file? In a Google Storage bucket?


Thank you for this approach;


Here is the error message I get:
File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in 
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'



Hey @Maximuluss,


This is a bash command. First, you should download it from your GCP panel -> Search for Credentials -> Create new Credential -> Service Account -> Add Key -> Download it as a JSON file. Then open the terminal and write: export  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/your/key.json"


Make sure to create a virtual environment and install the dependencies. In the terminal write: python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment -> source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate. At last, run pip install -r requirements.txt



Hi, I just posted the solution I came up with; Thank you for your help
